# Issue with subquery in mongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb, lookup, correlated-subquery

I wanted to do a simple subquery with MongoDB, however, after reading plenty of documentation, still don't get it :(
I was using similar code as without success: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

```
select count(*) from Table1 where Field1 in (SELECT Field2 FROM Table2 where Field3 in ('QWERTY','ASDDF'));
```

Can you please help on this?
Thank you.

**Edited:**
I've tried something like the below, but still missing the filter of the field3 in ...

```
db.getCollection("Table1").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {

                }, 
                "COUNT(*)" : {
                    "$sum" : NumberInt(1)
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : {
                "COUNT(*)" : "$COUNT(*)", 
                "_id" : NumberInt(0)
            }
        },
        {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "Table2",
            "localField": "Field1",
            "foreignField": "Field2" ,
            "as": "data"
            }
        },
{"$match": { "data.Field3": { "$in" : [ "QWERTY", "ASDDF" ]  } }}  
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : true
    }
);
```

Comment: Could you share and example of what you've tried that hasn't succeeded?

Comment: Hi Alex B, edited now

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have two collections like this

`collection1`

```
[
{
    "c" : 3,
    "field" : 3
},
{
    "b" : 2,
    "field" : 2
},
{
    "a" : 1,
    "field" : 1
}
]
```

`collection2`

```
[
{
    "field1" : 4,
    "field2" : "kghjfdsa"
},
{
    "field1" : 3,
    "field2" : "dsfdgfdghdf"
},
{
    "field1" : 2,
    "field2" : "fdsfsd"
},
{
    "field1" : 1,
    "field2" : "adasd"
}
]
```

For query your data you just need to run this query

```
db.collection2.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            field2: {
                $in: ["kghjfdsa", "fdsfsd", "adasd"]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "collection1",
            localField: "field1",
            foreignField: "field",
            as: "data"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
           "data.field": 1
        } 
    }
])
```

If I can help with anything else let me know:)

Comment: Hi @andranikasl, thanks for your answer.
I've tried that however, it is missing the filter of the foreignField "field".
Imagine that I want only the the ones that are field = 3.
I've been reading in the mentioned documentation that I should use "let" and/or "pipeline".

Comment: @PBR you can add `{
        $match: {
            "data.field": 1
        }
    }` after lookup

Comment: Hi Andranikasl, I really appreciate your answer. I'm close to it but still something is missing. As you can see in the initial query:
select count(*) from Table1 where Field1 in (SELECT Field2 FROM Table2 where Field3 in ('QWERTY','ASDDF'));
The field3 is different that the one that I'm comparing with and doing the lookup. Will it still work?